# Adding values from text file to arraylist in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a multiple choice java application in Android Studio, and I'm trying to get the code below to split my text file at each comma, essentially making the string before the comma index [0] and the string after the comma index [1]. What do I need to change in my code to make this work? My application keeps crashing on an outofbounds error when I try to use any value stored at [1]

```
    public class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity {
int sizeOfArray;
String[][] qAndA;//Stores Questions and Answers

String[] split = new String[5];
ArrayList<String>arrayListTerms = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String>arrayListDef = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, String> qMatch = new HashMap<>();//Matches correct answer with current question
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

public static final String TAG =" ";

//for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
//qAndA[0][i] = arrayListDef.get(i);
//}
//Switch & do same for questions
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
    BufferedReader myBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;

    try {

        while((line = myBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] split = line.split(Pattern.quote(","));
            String question1 = split[0];
            String question2 = split[1];
            lines.add(question1);
            lines.add(question2);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Textfile Loaded.");
        myBufferedReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to open text file.");
    } catch (IOException ex){
        Log.e(TAG, "Error reading text file.");
    }

    Collections.shuffle(arrayListDef);
    sizeOfArray = arrayListDef.size();
```

Comment: What is an example of your input? It sounds as if your string isn't being split. So split[0] holds the entire line and split[1] would be empty (non existent and out of bounds)

Comment: @Samuel It's coming from a text file like this: What language is most commonly used for Android application development?,Which of these programs is often used for Android application development?

Comment: I am with yannick1976. What happens when you use the simpler form String[] split = string.split(",");. It is possible that your pattern is trying to identify something different to just any , and as a result is never matching and if so never splitting the string.

Comment: the split method looks fine, have you tried to print out the original string "line" bevore you tryed to split it to make sure that your input is correct?

Comment: @Samuel I have removed the Pattern.quote() and it's still causing a crash. There's definitely something wrong with how I'm trying to split but I cannot figure it out

Comment: Just output each `line` you read from the file and you'll see where it breaks. Then, tell us what line makes your program break.

Comment: @tom3008 System.out.println(lines) gives me this, but I cant use any index other than 0. Each set of square brackets represents a new line.    [Java]  [Java, Android Studio] [Java, Android Studio, 2005] [Java, Android Studio, 2005, HTC Dream] So essentially, I can see that all my values are being read, but I have no idea how to access them outside of the text file

Comment: Where is your raw file can you show us the content ?

Comment: Java,What language is most commonly used for Android application development?
Android Studio,Which of these programs is often used for Android application development?
2005,In what year did Google acquire Android?
HTC Dream,What was the name of Android's first phone?
Ok Google,Which phrase has Android used to develop voice control technology?
Sandbox,Android's applications run in/on a:
Google Play,What is the Android app store called?
Marshmallow,What is Android's newest OS release called?
KitKat,Which Android operating system is named after a chocolate bar?
@Nader

Comment: @JeremyStone Does each of your lines have a coma? If you are reading the file line by line and splitting each line as it comes in you would have a problem with any line missing a coma. So if there are any breaks in there that count as a new line and no coma the split string would only have the 1 value and not 2.

Comment: î m actually not sure, where exactly the problem is located
so (as you said) you have the correct string in the line befor you try to split it? (just to go sure that we understand us, answer an easy yes pls ;) )
the next step ist to check the method alone
so pls create a new java test project (only java, not android) and test the your code local (with a given string, i. e. this on out of the task) 
tell us, weather it works or not, this is the next step, to locate the problem

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that one of the line that you are reading from the file doesn't contain any ',' and that is why you are getting index out of bound exception.
The reader you are using is reading a line by line bases that is why it just crashes when it reads a line that doesnt have a coma.

Another cause of this is that you file has an empty line at the end of it.

Comment: Java,What language is most commonly used for Android application development? This is my first line. There is a comma.

Comment: One if the lines doesn't ... i have edited the answer. @JeremyStone

Comment: Another thought would be make sure you do not have an empty line at the end of your file @JeremyStone

Comment: There's also not an empty line at the end of my file

Comment: @JeremyStone can you upload the file somewhere please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93934/discussion-between-nader-and-jeremy-stone).